# Isotope filtering and (un)filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been racking my brain all day over this and I'm no closer to brewing up a solution... I'm hoping you good people can help.

I've using isotope to filter results from a page, using classes pulled from the database to tag things such as category/ date of publish etc etc. I need for the users to be able to filter these. I'm doing this from a ul list with but one of the requirements is that the filters act as 'on and off' switches.

So, instead of using 'exactly' what I have at present...

```
// filter items when filter link is clicked
$(' ul.filteroption li').click(function(){
var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-value');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });
return false;
});
```

I was going to add a class to indicate if the li.filter ul li is on of off...

```
// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('ul.filteroption li.turnon').click(function(){
var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-value');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });
return false;
});
```

or

```
// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('ul.filteroption li.turnoff').click(function(){
var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-value');
$container.isotope({ filter: selector });
return false;
});
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do the opposite of what I'm asking the script turnon script does. EG... when user clicks on li.turnoff eliminate that selection from the filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all filters from your isotope container you have to set the filter to '*' so instead of:

```
filter: selector
```

in your "ul.filteroption li.turnoff" click binding, you need to change that to:

```
filter: '*'
```

and this will basically tell isotope to remove any filters that it had and display all elements of your container.

Comment: ah, I suspect i haven't been clear enough. Say i have four buttons (summer spring autumn winter) and pressing each of these filters to show their corresponding results. The button is now in its turned on state. Pressing the same button again then clears it's own data filter option, the button is now in its turned off state. Not all of them as * does. I know this won't work but something like this..

$container.isotope({ unfilter: selector });

Comment: Ah, so you probably want either (1) every time you detect a click on one of your list elements, clear your filter with '*' and then iterate over the other list elements and detect if they are in the turned on state and apply a filter for each one that is turned on or (2) have a global variable that stores the state of each of your options (ie if it is an object you could do: `filters.summer = true;`) and every time one of your filters gets click zero out your filter and apply them each one by one. Hopefully this helps. If you need clarification, i can throw together a fiddle and post it.

Comment: cheers for the help. your logic has helped. I didn't want you going out your way for me so I've managed to figure out a solution based on your suggestion. I've got a few bugs here and there but cheers for putting me on the right path.